# Can you cover or hide a outside meter box

Tags: electrical-panel

My wife and I are working on our backyard and the patio, and we need to find out if is legal to hide or cover a outside breaker/meter box in Texas?, it's only for aesthetic purposes. Thanks.

Comment: This was an obvious "no" back when a person had to drive around and read meters, but I wonder if anything has changed now that smart meters are in wide use.

Comment: If you put up a fence panel or something in front of the area but left enough space to walk behind it would probably be OK. You might call the utility company and ask how much space they require to be left open around the meter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because local ordinances are off-topic

Comment: I know in my area the meter face is required to be visible, if your main disconnect is located in that panel it is required to be accessible to fire personal. (Covering the panel may make it hard to find in the case of a fire). So if this also has your main disconnect you should contact your fire marshal to find out if a sign would be allowed or if it can have a access door.

Answer (score 3):

In Texas the meter must be visible for inspection by the utility company. The other part of this is clearances. You can put up a screen for visual effect but it has to meet all clearances required by both the Utility Company and the Municipality AHJ.

Remember you have to make two different authorities happy and possibly a HOA. Contact each one and they will give you the local statutes. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

- check with local utility (as others mentioned)
- ask the utility how they read meters (manual or electronic)
- modular, easy to open ( it will save your landscaping)
- air space around box (no critters)
- be prepared to replace the covering if box ever needs maintenance

I am in Oregon, not Texas, but as a someone who works for a public utility I recommend, as the other said to check with your utility.  That being said the worst the Utility will do it ask you to remove it ( you can ask what they do if the box isn't reachable.)  Most utilities, especially in larger cities, have electronic meter readers, meaning they get your readings by driving by your house, they usually don't look at your meters.  The other thing to consider is when covering your box make sure the covering can be opened easily, think hinges.  This way there will not be a problem.  Additionally consider leaving a gap around the box, several inches on all sides and enough for air circulation, slated wood is good because it distracts the eye, but people can find it if need be, and does not in courage critters to nest. Remember, if fire department wants to find it, they will rip off the covering and demolish anything you put around it ( and if you live near the sea (or gulf) chances are the utility will replace your meter every 10 years or so for corrosion,) so modular would be best.  And lastly, if you sell your home the home inspector will probably hate it.  But, I wouldn't worry about that until that comes about.  The new buyers will tell you what they need, and as long as it is removable no one will care.  Plus the bonus of seeming cooperative.

End note, utilities have a set way for doing everything, you can ask a ton of " what ifs ", even if they say no about disguising it, ask what happens if you do.  They know what happens, have specific rules and/or may have suggestions.  With utilities, it does not hurt to ask.  You can even ask why the rules are that way.  You can then choose your risk

Good luck